# product topology confusion

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ be a nonempty collection of nonempty
topological spaces.Then let $f: I \to I$ be a bijection. Of course, if $\alpha \in I$, then we can define the projection $\pi_\alpha : \prod_{i \in I} X_i \to X_\alpha$ by $\pi_\alpha((x_i)_{i \in I}) = x_\alpha$. However, how are we to define projections on $\prod_{i \in I} X_{f(i)}$?

Do we define $\rho_\alpha : \prod_{i \in I} X_{f(i)} \to X_\alpha$ by
$\rho_\alpha((x_{f(i)})_{i \in I}) = x_\alpha$?

This is important to me, since I want to be able to say something about the continuity of functions from $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ to $\prod_{i \in I} X_{f(i)}$.

Thanks.

Comment: I would use $\rho_\alpha \colon \prod\limits_{i\in I} X_{f(i)} \to X_{f(\alpha)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it either way,

$$\rho_\alpha:\prod_{i\in I}X_{f(i)}\to X_\alpha:\langle x_{f(i)}:i\in I\rangle\mapsto x_\alpha$$

or

$$\rho_\alpha:\prod_{i\in I}X_{f(i)}\to X_{f(\alpha)}:\langle x_{f(i)}:i\in I\rangle\mapsto x_{f(\alpha)}\;,$$

whichever is more convenient; just be sure to use it consistently the way you’ve defined it.